# Question about proof that $A_n$ is simple for $n > 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm a bit confused about [this proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=KVeXG163BggC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false) that $A_n$ is simple for $n > 4$.  The conclusion of the second paragraph is not clear to me.  Why is that $\sigma'\sigma^{-1}$ fixing fewer symbols than $\sigma$ a contradiction?

Comment: It appears to be a typo. What is meant is ***more*** symbols are fixed by $\sigma'\sigma^{-1}$, since $2$ is fixed as well as all fixed points of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The element $\sigma$ is chosen to fix the most symbols possible.

Comment: So why would $\sigma'\sigma^{-1}$ fixing less symbols be a contradiction?

Comment: As per peoplepower's comment, it should say more symbols.